# How to delete AWS Cognito Unconfirmed users from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, amazon-cognito

We have a huge number of Unconfirmed users in AWS congnito, so my requirement is to delete all of them from CLI instead of AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you were using the AWS CLI (Windows, Linux, etc.), but here's a script that will accomplish what you are trying to do. Note that your AWS CLI should be configured to output JSON for this to work. Also note that this takes a while to run. I deleted around 80 unconfirmed Cognito users with it and it took 5-6 minutes to complete.

### PowerShell

```powershell
# Update these to your AWS configuration
$AWS_REGION = 'your-aws-region'
$AWS_USER_POOL_ID = 'your-aws-userpool'

$userList = aws cognito-idp list-users --region $AWS_REGION --user-pool-id $AWS_USER_POOL_ID | ConvertFrom-Json
$userList.Users | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.UserStatus -like 'UNCONFIRMED'){
        aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --region $AWS_REGION --user-pool-id $AWS_USER_POOL_ID --username $_.Username
    }  
}
```